# Linux:AWK gsub command not processing correct output

Tags: linux, bash, csv

On the below csv file I would like to change the scope from ENG to PROD; I have used the following awk command but there is no change to the file, could anyone please tell me what is wrong?

test.csv

```
1,test1,scope=ENG
2,test2,scope=ENG
```

bash snippet

```
awk -F"," '{ gsub("scope\s*=\s*ENG","PROD",$3); print }' ./test.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not telling AWK to subsitute in place. Not all versions allow doing that in any case.

A better solution:

```
sed -i 's/\(scope\s*=\s*\)ENG/\1PROD/' test.csv
```

Comment: Thanks I have overcome the issue and yes using sed is actually a better tool for the job.